# Copy database from SQL Server 2000 to SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm trying to transfer a database from SQL server 2000 to SQL Server 2008 using the copy database wizard, but I keep getting an error that tells me to check my error logs.  I go check the log and there is nothing on the error.  Has anyone had a problem with the copy database wizard and knows a fix for the problem or is there a better method to transfer the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you run the Upgrade Advisor? SQL Server 2008 isn't entirely backward compatible with 2000, so there might be some incompatibilities...

Comment: I did, and it is saying that the Full-Text Search is keeping it from being transfered.  I guess its a feature in 2000 and 2005 but not in 2008.

Comment: Try this: http://www.dbforums.com/microsoft-sql-server/1643363-how-uninstall-full-text-search-sql-2000-a.html

Answer (score 0):

backup and restore?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check both the SQL Server logs and the Windows Event Logs?

Comment: Just the SQL Server logs I'll check the windows event logs.